# how to write php variable inside style in cakephp 3.x checkbox?

Tags: php, cakephp

```
<?php


if ($checkbox == 1) {
    $checked = 'checked';
} {
    $checked = '';
}
echo $this->Form->input('Off Line Quotes', array(
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'checked' => $checked,
    'class' => 'inline',
    'id' => 'editcheckbox_quotes',
    'format' => array(
        'before',
        'input',
        'between',
        'label',
        'after',
        'error'
    )
));
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to put else in front of { $checked = ''}

Comment: Also, be sure to properly format your code, @Bhinal.  It will help you see problems more easily.  I reformatted your original post because it was so hard to read and now the problem is quite clear.  You can use [PHPFormatter](http://beta.phpformatter.com/) or an IDE.